# React Native FlatList with columns does not allow horizontal scrolling on Android, but it does on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm working on a minesweeper game with React Native. On iOS, I am able to scroll horizontally and vertically. But on Android, I can only scroll vertically.

I've tried modifying the layout and justification of content of the different views, but nothing seems to work.

Here is a shortened version of the code:

```
const Board = (
    {game}: {game: Game}
) => {

    //...

    return (
        <SafeAreaView
            style={styles.main}
        >
            <FlatList
                style={styles.flatList}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
                data={game.board.grid.flat()}
                numColumns={game.size} // n x n grid, so n columns
                columnWrapperStyle={{ flexWrap: "nowrap" }}
                renderItem={({ item: square }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.square}>
                            {/* ... */}
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "black"
    },
    flatList: {

    },
    contentContainer: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    square: {
        width: 35,
        height: 35,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        margin: 1
    }
});
```

[image: Android screenshot]

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `ScrollView` with property `horizontal` to wrap the `FlatList`. The code should be like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

/**
 * This function creates an array based on the `quantity` value
 */
const placeholderData = (quantity = 16) => (
  Array.from(Array(quantity).keys()).map((item) => ({ id: item }))
)

const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 60
const NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 60
const NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS * NUMBER_OF_ROWS

export default function App() {
  const renderItem = () => (
    <View style={styles.square} />
  )

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={styles.container}
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
      <FlatList
        data={placeholderData(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS)}
        keyExtractor={({id}) => id.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        numColumns={NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  square: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#696969',
    margin: 1,
  },
});
```

If you prefer, I create a [snack on Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@marcelofreires/stackoverflow-questions-72631783) for you to see the complete example running. Just scan the QR Code from your smartphone using the [Expo Go App](https://expo.dev/client).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this approach and it does allow me to scroll horizontally as well as vertically. However, it does not allow me to scroll diagonally now.

I wonder if there is a way to make the parent ScrollView  allow a child scroll view to also handle input events at the same time.

Comment: Still, your solution does solve the original problem. I'm going to use your nested approach when Platform.OS === "android" :D